# connecting bulk propane to generator

Tags: electrical, heating, generator, propane

I live in a rural area and have a ~125 gallon propane tank on a concrete slab that is serviced by a mobile propane delivery company. We use it for hot water, the gas range, and our forced air heating system rarely since we primarily rely on the abundant wood. This is my outside tank:

[image]

Also because we're in a rural mountain town we lose electricity sometimes. We have a gas/propane duel-fuel generator connected to our house with a generator transfer / interrupt panel. We have a 30lb propane tank and maybe ~20 gallons of gasoline hanging around.

The propane tank and connection I use for running the generator:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/pRo6Vce.jpg]

I was wondering what it would take to connect my larger tank to my generator. I'm fine with having a propane-plumber do it, but I'd still like to know the pieces involved. Fundamentally I don't want to end up in a situation where I'm out of propane for my generator while still having 100 gallons 15 feet away.

Comment: So are you wanting to "hot swap" the 30lb tank and the larger tank or just replace the 30lb tank altogether?

Comment: @JPhi1618 more on the "hot swap" side I think, but I guess it depends on the options of what it looks like to have something permanently installed.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you fit a second regulator to the supply from the large tank. This may sensibly require a larger pipe or the use of a different "tap" on the tank if there is one.

You should fit isolation valves so that you have full control over what is supplied when.

The second regulator is to avoid any restriction of the supply to either house or generator. You may well have to have some spark arrest devices by code depending on area and common sense suggests you should have them anyway.

Comment: There's a grounding strap on the pipe delivered into an in-ground copper rod, not sure if that's the spark arrestor you're talking about. I'll hit up a propane plumber and run your ideas past them; the more I look at it the more I think that's going to be the case.

Comment: I was thinking of if the generator engine backfires... but the grounding strap is also good. Also, talk to a shop that fits lpg tanks to cars as they will also know what is necessary.